# GitHub co-authored-by with private noreply address

Tags: github

Is it possible to use a no-reply address (like `123456+username@users.noreply.github.com`) in [a co-authored-by commit trailer](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-commit-with-multiple-authors/) if the account holder has selected the "Block command line pushes that expose my email" option? In my testing it seems that that option is all or nothing, as in, you can select that and block both your primary address that you've chosen to be private (with the "Keep my email address private" option) *and your no-reply address*. What I expected would be that your no-reply address wouldn't ever be blocked from a commit message, because, isn't that the point of a no-reply address?

Put another way: I want to be able to add a co-authored-by credit for a member of the team that chooses to have their email address private. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This was all my mistake! I was using a backup email address as my `user.email` and GitHub was flagging that *not* the other user's no-reply address. Once I changed my `user.email` to my no-reply the push went through (after running a `git commit --amend` plus a flag for changing the author to my no-reply).