# Git magic keywords in commit messages (Signed-off-by, Co-authored-by, Fixes, ...)

Tags: git, github, gitlab, commit-message

Git command itself [supports](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) the `Signed-off-by: Person's name <persons@email>` line.

GitHub [adds](https://help.github.com/en/github/committing-changes-to-your-project/creating-a-commit-with-multiple-authors) `Co-authored-by:` line, which then shows both the committer and the referenced person as commit authors in the UI. (See Q: [GitHub co-authored-by with private noreply address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54076863/github-co-authored-by-with-private-noreply-address) for discussion how to avoid exposing email addresses.)

Futhermore, [GitHub](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/closing-issues-using-keywords) and [GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/managing_issues.html#default-closing-pattern) each recognize a set of keywords to close issues when a commit is merged.

Is the list of Git magic keywords above complete? Is there a standardization process for adding these lines and keywords? Are these defined to be case insensitive?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54076863/github-co-authored-by-with-private-noreply-address for discussion how to avoid exposing email addresses.

Comment: Since Git 232 (Q2 2021), you can add any trailer with `git commit --trailer "xxx Person's name <persons@email>"`. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67040353/6309)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the OP:

> The `git` command itself supports the `Signed-off-by: Person's name <persons@email>` line.

Starting with Git 2.32 (Q2 2021), the `git` command itself supports... any trailer you want!

"[`git commit`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/68e15e0c231bfa50e254fc87d054649161a7e301/Documentation/git-commit.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit))</sup> learned `--trailer <key>[=<value>]` option; together with the interpret-trailers command, this will make it easier to support custom trailers.

See [commit 2daae3d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2daae3d1d1bf513f1e1c00f1e4df75e1cb500e0f) (23 Mar 2021) by [ZheNing Hu (`adlternative`)](https://github.com/adlternative).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 68e15e0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/68e15e0c231bfa50e254fc87d054649161a7e301), 07 Apr 2021)</sup>

> ### [`commit`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2daae3d1d1bf513f1e1c00f1e4df75e1cb500e0f): add --trailer option
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: ZheNing Hu</sup>

> Historically, Git has supported the '`Signed-off-by`' commit trailer using the '`--signoff`' and the '`-s`' option from the command line.
> But users may need to provide other trailer information from the command line such as "`Helped-by`", "`Reported-by`", "`Mentored-by`",
>
> Now implement a new `--trailer <token>[(=|:)<value>]` option to pass other trailers to `interpret-trailers` and insert them into commit messages.

`git commit` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2daae3d1d1bf513f1e1c00f1e4df75e1cb500e0f/Documentation/git-commit.txt#L170-L180):

> ### `--trailer <token>[(=|:)<value>]`
>
> Specify a (`<token>`, `<value>`) pair that should be applied as a
> trailer.
>
> For instance:
>
> ```sh
> git commit --trailer "Signed-off-by:C O Mitter <committer@example.com>" \
>            --trailer "Helped-by:C O Mitter <committer@example.com>"
> ```
>
> That will add the "`Signed-off-by`" trailer *and* the "`Helped-by`" trailer to the commit message.
>
> The `trailer.*` configuration variables
> ([`git interpret-trailers`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-interpret-trailers)) can be used to define if
> a duplicated trailer is omitted, where in the run of trailers
> each trailer would appear, and other details.

---

Regarding that `trailer.xxx` configuration, consider an initial commit that you want to amend with *additional* trailers:

```
Signed-off-by: C O Mitter <committer@example.com>
Signed-off-by: C1 E1
Reported-by: C3 E3
Mentored-by: C4 E4
Helped-by: C3 E3
```

A `trailer.ifexists="replace"` config would, if you amend it by adding the *same* Reported-by, keep the message unchanged:

```
git -c trailer.ifexists="replace" \
    commit   --trailer "Mentored-by: C4 E4" \
             --trailer "Helped-by: C3 E3" \
             --amend
```

But if you amend the same commit with `trailer.ifexists="add"` would means:

```
Signed-off-by: C O Mitter <committer@example.com>
Signed-off-by: C1 E1
Helped-by: C2 E2
Reported-by: C3 E3
Mentored-by: C4 E4
Reported-by: C3 E3  <<<< added twice
Mentored-by: C4 E4  <<<< added twice
```

And using `trailer.ifexists="addIfDifferent"`

```sh
git -c trailer.ifexists="addIfDifferent" \
    commit  --trailer "Reported-by: C3 E3" \
            --trailer "Mentored-by: C5 E5" \
            --amend
```

And you get:

```
Signed-off-by: C O Mitter <committer@example.com>
Signed-off-by: C1 E1
Helped-by: C2 E2
Reported-by: C3 E3
Mentored-by: C4 E4
Mentored-by: C5 E5  <<<< Only C5 E5 is added
```

---

And, still With Git 2.32 (Q2 2021), the way the command line specified by the `trailer.<token>.command` configuration variable receives the end-user supplied value was both error prone and misleading.
An alternative to achieve the same goal in a safer and more intuitive way has been added, as the `trailer.<token>.cmd` configuration variable, to replace it.

See [commit c364b7e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c364b7ef51ec3af871754e7afdfd73e4bed6da56), [commit 57dcb65](https://github.com/git/git/commit/57dcb6575b577a70f02814df4291e8af6ed81f86) (03 May 2021) by [ZheNing Hu (`adlternative`)](https://github.com/adlternative).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2cd6ce2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2cd6ce21f38b9dab1b3a75f05b24e92bdc4b5b93), 11 May 2021)</sup>

> ### [`trailer`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c364b7ef51ec3af871754e7afdfd73e4bed6da56): add new .cmd config option
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Christian Couder</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: ZheNing Hu</sup>

> The `trailer.<token>.command` configuration variable specifies a command (run via the shell, so it does not have to be a single name or path to the command, but can be a shell script), and the first occurrence of substring `$ARG` is replaced with the value given to the `interpret-trailer` command for the token in a '`--trailer <token>=<value>`' argument.
>
> This has three downsides:
>
> - The use of `$ARG` in the mechanism misleads the users that
>   the value is passed in the shell variable, and tempt them to use `$ARG` more than once, but that would not work, as the second and subsequent `$ARG` are not replaced.
> - Because `$ARG` is textually replaced without regard to the
>   shell language syntax, even '`$ARG`' (inside a single-quote pair), which a user would expect to stay intact, would be replaced, and worse, if the value had an unmatched single quote (imagine a name like "O'Connor", substituted into `NAME='$ARG'` to make it `NAME='O'Connor'`), it would result in a broken command that is not syntactically correct (or worse).
> - The first occurrence of substring `$ARG` will be replaced with the empty string, in the command when the command is first called to add a trailer with the specified `<token>`.
>   This is a bad design, the nature of automatic execution causes it to add a trailer that we don't expect.
>
> Introduce a new `trailer.<token>.cmd` configuration that takes higher precedence to deprecate and eventually remove `trailer.<token>.command`, which passes the value as an argument to the command.
> Instead of "`$ARG`", users can refer to the value as positional argument, $1, in their scripts.
> At the same time, in order to allow [`git interpret-trailers`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c364b7ef51ec3af871754e7afdfd73e4bed6da56/Documentation/git-interpret-trailers.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-interpret-trailers))</sup> to better simulate the behavior of git command `-s`, '`trailer.<token>.cmd`' will not automatically execute.

`git interpret-trailers` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c364b7ef51ec3af871754e7afdfd73e4bed6da56/Documentation/git-interpret-trailers.txt#L235-L248):

> This option behaves in the same way as '`trailer.<token>.cmd`', except
> that it doesn't pass anything as argument to the specified command.
> Instead the first occurrence of substring `$ARG` is replaced by the
> value that would be passed as argument.
>
> The '`trailer.<token>.command`' option has been deprecated in favor of
> '`trailer.<token>.cmd`' due to the fact that `$ARG` in the user's command is
> only replaced once and that the original way of replacing `$ARG` is not safe.
>
> When both '`trailer.<token>.cmd`' and '`trailer.<token>.command`' are given
> for the same `<token>`, '`trailer.<token>.cmd`' is used and
> '`trailer.<token>.command`' is ignored.
>
> ### `trailer.<token>.cmd`

`git interpret-trailers` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c364b7ef51ec3af871754e7afdfd73e4bed6da56/Documentation/git-interpret-trailers.txt#L264-L266):

> of these arguments, if any, will be passed to the command as its
> first argument.
> This way the command can produce a  computed
> from the `<value>` passed in the '`--trailer <token>=<value>`' argument.

`git interpret-trailers` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c364b7ef51ec3af871754e7afdfd73e4bed6da56/Documentation/git-interpret-trailers.txt#L349-L397):

> - Configure a 'help' trailer with a cmd use a script `glog-find-author`
>   which search specified author identity from git log in git repository
>   and show how it works:
>
> ```sh
> $ cat ~/bin/glog-find-author
> #!/bin/sh
> test -n "$1" && git log --author="$1" --pretty="%an <%ae>" -1 || true
> $ git config trailer.help.key "Helped-by: "
> $ git config trailer.help.ifExists "addIfDifferentNeighbor"
> $ git config trailer.help.cmd "~/bin/glog-find-author"
> $ git interpret-trailers --trailer="help:Junio" --trailer="help:Couder" <<EOF
> > subject
> >
> > message
> >
> > EOF
> subject
>
> message
>
> Helped-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
> Helped-by: Christian Couder <christian.couder@gmail.com>
> ```
>
> - Configure a 'ref' trailer with a cmd use a script `glog-grep`
>   to grep last relevant commit from git log in the git repository
>   and show how it works:
>
> ```sh
> $ cat ~/bin/glog-grep
> #!/bin/sh
> test -n "$1" && git log --grep "$1" --pretty=reference -1 || true
> $ git config trailer.ref.key "Reference-to: "
> $ git config trailer.ref.ifExists "replace"
> $ git config trailer.ref.cmd "~/bin/glog-grep"
> $ git interpret-trailers --trailer="ref:Add copyright notices." <<EOF
> > subject
> >
> > message
> >
> > EOF
> subject
>
> message
>
> Reference-to: 8bc9a0c769 (Add copyright notices., 2005-04-07)
> ```

Comment: Mmm "Charlie-Oscar Mitter"? "Charlotte-Olivia Mitter"? I have to know.

Comment: See also [Git 2.41, Q2 2023](https://github.com/git/git/commit/66077a29e18d6e3918982a00bd91cedbf1986ae2)

Answer (score 10):

These are called trailers, and can be pretty much any key-value pair. There is no standardization process and interpretation of trailer lines is platform-dependent (e.g. GitHub, GitLab). See also the [documentation for git-interpret-trailers](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-interpret-trailers).

Edit: [here](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/CommitMessageConventions) is some information on some additional trailers used by different tools.

Edit (2): Git itself has some built-in support for a "Signed-off-by: " trailer line as well as a "(cherry picked from commit " trailer line. See [git_generated_prefixes in trailer.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6e0cc6776106079ed4efa0cc9abace4107657abf/trailer.c#L49) as well as [the constants in sequencer.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/108b97dc372828f0e72e56bbb40cae8e1e83ece6/sequencer.c#L38).