# `git log --name-only` show coauthors

Tags: git, git-log

Although I have added Co-authored-by: in the commit message, `git log --name-only` only shows one author, not the others, how can I make git show the coauthors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, in that it is a [trailer](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt-emtrailersoptionsem):

```
git log --format="%h %s %an Co-author:%(trailers:key=Co-authored-by)"
```

While it is true Git knows nothing about it, the trailer scheme allows to add any `key=value` you want to the commit message.

Since [Git 2.32](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67040353/6309) (Q2 2021), you can make a commit with any trailer you want.

```
git commit --trailer "Signed-off-by:C O Mitter <committer@example.com>" \
           --trailer "Helped-by:C O Mitter <committer@example.com>"
```

Answer (score 2):

> how can I make git show the coauthors

You can't. Git commits don't have coauthors. There is a GitHub coauthor feature, and other hosting milieus may support that sort of thing too; but Git itself knows nothing of it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can’t do this with `git log`. But you can credit co-authors in `git shortlog`.

From `man git shortlog`:

```
--group=<type>

[…]

  If --group is specified multiple times, commits are counted under
  each value (but again, only once per unique value in that
  commit). For example, git shortlog --group=author
  --group=trailer:co-authored-by counts both authors and co-authors.
```

Commit:

```
commit f0897445bfe6d41ff352a7e9f352956d1ebee63d (HEAD -> main)
Author: Cristobal Hill <noreply@cribal.kz>
Date:   Wed Mar 15 22:01:53 2023 +0100

    First commit!

    Co-authored-by: Henrietta Fjord <hfj@underhillhosting.com>
```

With `git shortlog`:

```
Cristobal Hill (1):
      First commit!
```

With `git shortlog --group=author --group=trailer:co-authored-by`:

```
Henrietta Fjord (1):
      First commit!

Cristobal Hill (1):
      First commit!
```